# Weird "distortions" in renders but not in the viewport preview

Tags: rendering

First of all, I would like to say that I am not an expert at all, so I might not know something very obvious and I might even use the wrong words.

I am trying to solve this problem: I like what I see in the viewport render preview, but once I render, I see weird "distortions" (I am attaching pictures of both the viewport preview and final render). You can see them at the edge of the shadow, just under the windows and on the door.

What am I doing wrong?[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify 'distortions'?

Comment: In the second picture that I attached (the final render) you can see how the edge of the shadow is not smooth like in the viewport render preview, but it's kinda "jagged"... English is not my first language I hope I still made myself clear.

Comment: Those might be artefacts from whatever you do in post processing

Comment: What do you mean? The second picture is straight out of blender, I did not do anything to it...

Comment: are you using denoise?

Comment: @tommaso Straight out of Blender doesn't necessarily mean no post processing... Frederik means processing done post rendering - and there you clearly did something since it looks like you used a _Glare_ node in compositing...